# Cannot connect to Google Directions API with Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, callback, google-api

I am trying to connect to the Google Directions API with my node server via a callback function but for some reason I cannot get a response from the Google API.  Funny enough I had this working a few days ago and somehow I managed to break it.  My controller contains the following code - calling a function within google_api.js:

```
var google = require('../scripts/google_api')    

var inputs = {
  origin: "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA",
  destination: "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014, USA",
  mode: "driving",
};

function getDirections(data, callback){
  console.log("First");
  callback(data);
  console.log("Second");
};
getDirections(inputs, google.directions);
```

My google_api.js file contains the following code (with a valid API key):

```
var googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
  key: 'XXX'
});

module.exports.directions = (req, res) => {

  console.log(req);

  googleMapsClient.directions({
  origin: req.origin,
  destination: req.destination,
  mode: req.mode,

  }, function(err, response) {
    if (!err) {
    console.log(response.json.results);
    };
  });
};
```

console.log("First"), console.log("Second") and console.log(req) all behave as expected so the problem must exist inside the googleMapsClient.directions() function.  The API key is tested and works with another front-end JS function so it isn't a problem with the key.  I managed to get the function to output an error once with a EHOSTUNREACH error but replicating this has not been consistent.  I fear I am missing something so basic that I don't even know where to begin.  Any help would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
**
```

> Asked long time ago, just posting a working code if anybody comes across and want to
>   implementing this google api.

**

```
var googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
  key: xxxxxxxxxx
});

function getDirections (req, callback)  {
  googleMapsClient.directions({
  origin: req.origin,
  destination: req.destination,
  mode: req.mode,

  }, function(err, response) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(response);
    if (!err) { 
    callback(response.json.results);
    };
  });
};

var inputs = {
  origin: "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA",
  destination: "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014, USA",
  mode: "driving",
};

getDirections(inputs, function(result){
console.log("Response: ", result)
});
```