# Google apis for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-maps

Am trying to build a server on NodeJS, I want to create a n api the simply takes two points and uses a google api and creates a route, I got lost in web, any recommendation for tutorials is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

What you need here is a [Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) or  [Direction Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), it can calculate directions (using a variety of methods of transportation) by using the `DirectionsService` object. This object communicates with the Google Maps API Directions Service which receives direction requests and returns an efficient path. You may either handle these directions results yourself or use the `DirectionsRenderer` object to render these results.

The Directions service can return multi-part directions using a series of waypoints. Directions are displayed as a polyline drawing the route on a map.

Here are the sample jsfiddle for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/gHK7s/2/ and http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/u9no8te4/

Now, to connect it with the Node.js that you want, you can check these SO questions on how to do that.

- [Using Node.js to connect to a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148403)
- [Cannot connect to Google Directions API with Node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379054)

For more information, check this [Node.js Client for Google Maps Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js)